# When can I apply the step $X + t Z = X \left( I + t X^{-\frac{1}{2}} Z X^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, positive-definite

I was just looking at a solution to a question in Boyd & Vandenberghe's  [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) (3.18-A) in which I'm asked to prove that the function: $f(X) = \mbox{tr}(X^{-1})$ is convex on $\textbf{dom}(f) = S_{++}^n$, where $S_{++}^n$ is the set of all symmetric positive definite matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

In the solution (which I understood), was a step that I would like to dwell on:

We apply the function $f(X)$ on the restriction of all linear lines, which in our case:
$$g(t) = f(X + tZ)$$
$$X \succ0,\ \  t\in \mathbb{R}, \ \ V\in S^n$$

$$g(t) = f\Big((X+tZ)^{-1}\Big) = f\Big((X^{-1}[I+tX^{-\frac{1}{2}} ZX^{-\frac{1}{2}} ]^{-1}\Big)$$

Now what I did was:

$$g(t) = f\Big((X+tZ)^{-1}\Big) = f\Big((X^{-1}[I+tX^{-1} Z]^{-1}\Big)$$

After looking a lot I've seen that a symmetric matrix has a symmetric square root if and only if it's positive semi-definite:

[Does a symmetric matrix necessarily have a symmetric square root?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517797/does-a-symmetric-matrix-necessarily-have-a-symmetric-square-root)

Now since $X \succ0$ then $X^{-1} \succ0$ and symmetric, so there exists such $X^{-\frac{1}{2}}={X^{-\frac{1}{2}}}^T$, and if so, I can totally justify the move $tX^{-1} Z = tX^{-\frac{1}{2}} ZX^{-\frac{1}{2}} $.

What I'd like to know is when can I use this move, under what conditions, and if I can apply it more generally. If this law has a proof or a known name I'd like to be referenced because i could now find anything

Comment: See the answers to these questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116259/commutativity-of-matrix-square-root) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116259/commutativity-of-matrix-square-root)

Comment: Both links lead to the same page, but thanks

Comment: @LinAlg So do you basically say that in order to use this equality the matrix I want to split should be PSD matrix?

Comment: if it's PSD then you can apply it, but the reverse is not always true ($Z=O$ is one example, I don't know of others)

Comment: Added to [The List](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790).

Answer (score 0):

I think the author simply means to adapt the strategy of considering the second-order directional derivative of $f$, rather than to modify the details of his proof for the convexity of log determinant. E.g. if we define $g(t)=f(Z+tV)$ where $Z\succ0$ and $V$ is symmetric, then for sufficiently small $t$, we have
\begin{aligned}
g(t)
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((Z+tV)^{-1}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left((I+tZ^{-1}V)^{-1}Z^{-1}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\left[I-tZ^{-1}V+t^2(Z^{-1}V)^2-t^3(Z^{-1}V)^3+\cdots\right]Z^{-1}\right).
\end{aligned}
When $V=0$, $g''(t)=0$ for all $t$. When $V\ne0$, we have $g''(0)=2\|Z^{-1/2}VZ^{-1}\|_F^2>0$ and in turn, $g''(t)>0$ when $t$ is sufficiently small. It follows that $f$ is locally convex at every $Z\succ0$. Consequently, $f$ is convex on $S^n_{++}$ because $S^n_{++}$ is a convex set.

Comment: How does $g''(t)>0$ follow from $g''(0) > 0$?

Comment: @dineshdileep The series expansion of $g$ is analytic on the disc $|t|<\|Z^{-1}V\|^{-1}$. Hence $g''$ is continuous at zero. Or easier: $\operatorname{tr}\left((Z+tV)^{-1}\right)=\frac{\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{adj}(Z+tV)))}{\det(Z+tV)}$ is a rational function in $t$ whose denominator is nonzero when $t$ is small. Hence $g''$ is continuous.

Comment: That is a well put answer - but it's not the answer to what I was asking